# Proving concurrence in a convex quadrilateral and circumcircles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral in which $AB = CD$ and $∠ABD + ∠ACD = 180^{\circ}$.
Lines $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $P$ and let $M$ be the midpoint of $AD$. Suppose that $MB$ and
$MC$ intersect the circumcircle of $\triangle{BPC}$ again at $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Prove that lines
$CX, BY , AD$ are concurrent.

When I first encountered the problem, I thought about some Ceva's Theorem. I drew the diagram, but couldn't make much sense of it. However, I couldn't find any more information about the lengths. Maybe something else could work. I haven't figured exactly what the first two conditions really can do, so can someone help?

Comment: Just a suggestion on using the first two conditions:- We can reflect C about AD to C. Then the supplementary sum implies ABDC’ is cyclic. Since C’D = CD = AB, chord AB and chord C’D are of equal length.

Comment: Letting $\angle ABD = \angle ACD = 90^\circ$ seems to provide a contradiction.

Comment: Indeed, as I can't construct it as that, unless we are given a self-intersecting quadrilateral.

Comment: However, they do intersect at point infinity on $AD$.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a point $B'$ such that $ABDB'$ is a parallelogram. Then, 
$$
\angle ACD+\angle AB'D=\angle ACD+\angle ABD=180^{\circ},
$$
so the quadrilateral $ACDB'$ is cyclic. We will prove that $X$ lies on the circumcircle of $ACDB'$. Indeed, note that (lines $BD$ and $AB'$ are parallel)
$$
\angle B'XC=180^{\circ}-\angle BXC=180^{\circ}-\angle BPC=180^{\circ}-\angle APD=\angle B'AP=\angle B'AC,
$$
so $X$ lies on the circumcircle of the quadrilateral $ACDB'$.

Similarly we can define the point $C'$ such that $ACDC'$ is parallelogram and analogously we can prove that points $A$, $B$, $D$, $C'$ and $Y$ are lying on the same circle. Thus, we have three circles: the circumcircle of $AXCDB'$, the circumcircle $ABDYC'$ and the circumcircle of $BXCPY$. Finally, note that corresponding radical axes are $AD$, $BY$ and $CX$. Hence, lines $AD$, $BX$ and $CY$ are concurrent, as desired.

Comment: If someone want to make diagram, you're welcome. Feel free to edit the answer.